# Android webkit html video gioto fullscreen event

Tags: html, video, html5-video, android-video-player

There's a problem: android webkit draws video-element and I want to catch transition to the fullscreen when I press on the fullscreen-button that situates on the bottom to the right of video element. I can't do that. There's no such event as 'fullscreen' or smth else like this. Can you help me? For catching events I use JavaScript codes.

Thx in advance.

Comment: I am encountering this problem as well.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Android 3.1+ for testing?
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html

Previous versions did not support inline video. If you want to catch the event you will have to disable default controls and implement your own as there is no "enterFullscreen" event for the native controls (neither is there one for you own controls but you could start whatever you want upon clicking your own FS button) - again, this wont work on version 3.0 or earlier. AND you won't have native fullscreen afterwards. Android's implementation of html5 video is rather poor.

I did not yet test Android 4.0 on that matter, meaning it could be better there.